# How to Capture ENTER Key which is pressed in TextBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am developing a simple chat system in ASP.NET with C# (Its a website not windows application). I am showing a chat window which contains a TextBox so that user can write his/her message in it. What i want is that when user presses ENTER key then I will be able to capture that ENTER pressed event and could call a function which will be in .cs file. How can i do that? This is the code segment from my project:

```
    <!-- Some code here -->

    <asp:textbox TextMode="Multiline"
    Columns="28"
    id="Textbox1"
    Rows="5"
    runat="server"
    BorderStyle="Solid"
    BorderColor="Bisque"
    class="msg-area">
    </asp:textbox>

</asp:Panel>
```

Thank You.

Comment: How about subscribing to the submit event of the containing form?

Comment: I dont have idea how to do that. The Form is created in master file and in this file (of chat window) there is only asp:Panel tag which contains this TextBox (as you can see in above code)!

Comment: Depends on which javascript library you're using. For jQuery look at: http://api.jquery.com/submit/ Then you probably need to put an ajax request into the submit handler.

Comment: Is it possible to add a button here then you can use the `defaultButton` property of the panel

Comment: I do not want to use Javascript for this purpose. I need to do this using C# (using .cs file). Basically i have written a function in .cs file which should be called when user presses ENTER key in TextBox in .aspx file. The problem is that i don't know how to call that function when user presses ENTER key within TextBox!!! 
I hope you understand my problem now.
Thanks...

Comment: The keypress is a client side event that needs to be handled on the client side using something like javascript.

Comment: <asp:textbox TextMode="Multiline"
    Columns="28"
    id="Textbox1"
    Rows="5"
    runat="server"
    BorderStyle="Solid"
    BorderColor="Bisque"
    class="msg-area" 
<b>OnEnterPressed="MyFunction"</b> >
    </asp:textbox>  
I have also tried the defaultbutton property of Panel but its not working!
any suggestions?

Comment: That doesn't appear to be valid xml.  Things like defaultbutton control the posting back of the form.  Most browsers will submit the form when enter is pressed unless it is pressed inside a multiline textbox in which case the enter key will add a newline to the textbox.  If you want to override this you will need javascript.

Comment: I agree with @V4Vendetta, it seems assigning a defaultbutton is the way to go (if you really wanted the JavaScript/jQuery-less solution). See Scott Gu's post about this: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2005/08/04/421647.aspx

Comment: @Anne i think it won't work for multiline textbox since they are textareas and have a different usage for Enter key

Answer (score 0):

Since it is a multiline text box you would have to handle one of the key press events and have it postback the form so you can handle it on the server.  You could also do a callback or ajax call but either way you need to have a javascript event handler initiate a call to the server so your c# code can run.   I need more detail about what your trying to do and what your using to give a more detailed answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think doing this kind of thing on the client side with AJAX is the best way to go. In javascript, to capture the enter key, use ascii value 13. If the user presses the key, gather the data and make an ajax call. On the server-side use a WebMethod to handle the call. Using jQuery, reference your textbox by it's class and not the ID... the ID won't work because asp.net adds it's own identifiers to the id when it renders the page. So, to get the value out of the textbox, do

```
var msgValue = $(".msg-area").val()
```

To call your function on the server-side, do something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "yourwebpage.aspx/PostChat,
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    processData: false,
    global: false,
    success: function (data) {
        ajaxData = data;
        ajaxResult = true;
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        ajaxResult = false;
    }
});
```

Finally, on the server-side, you add a function like so:

```
    [System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
    public static void PostChat()
    {
         /* post chat code here */
    }
```

There are a couple of details left out here (like in the PostChat() method you will want to pass in some data like PostChat(SomeObjectContainingChatData) as a JSON object and deserialize, but this gives you the general idea!

Answer (score 0):

Quick implementation of capturing the textbox via jQuery:

```
$.fn.captureEnter = function(options) {
// Parameters = OBJECT {action, preventDefault}
// action - Javascript function to be called upon the enter keypress. Send NULL to perform NO ACTION
// preventDefault - Set to FALSE if you don't want to return FALSE
var defaults = {
    action: function() {
        alert('The enter button has been captured. Please provide a function to run on enter.');
    },
    preventDefault: true
};
options = $.extend(defaults, options);

return this.each(function() {
    var el = this;
    $(el).keypress(function(e) {
        var code = e.keyCode || e.which;
        if (code == 13) { //Enter keycode
            if ((typeof options.action) == "function") {
                options.action(el);
            }

            if (options.preventDefault) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }

        }
    });
});
```

};

```
$('TEXTBOX').captureEnter({
    action: postMessageAjaxFunction
});
```